# adding php to .tpl to check cookie value

Tags: php, cookies, smarty, echo

I'm trying to add a php script to a .tpl file that checks whether or not a cookie has been set:

`<?php if (isset($_COOKIE['IA'])) echo "?campaign=333"; if (isset($_COOKIE['IA']) && isset($_COOKIE['Ptag'])) echo "&p=" . $_COOKIE['Ptag'] ;?>`

I've tried including the php in {php} code {/php} and also {php} /file/function.php {/php}. 
I've also tried code.

However, nothing seems to work. can any one help?

Comment: That's missing the point of templates. Put the cookie check in the PHP that *calls* the template, and add the result of that check to the data you inject into the template.

Comment: What is the code? Did you include smarty? Normally [{php}](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.php.tpl) works

Comment: never add a php script in .tpl file. Just pass the output of your php script to ..tpl using $smarty->assign....

Answer (score 1):

Use the smarty predefined variables:
http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl

for example:

`{if $smarty.cookies.IA}?campaign=333{/if}{if $smarty.cookies.IA && $smarty.cookies.Ptag}&p={$smarty.cookies.Ptag}{/id}`

this reveals some security problem such as XSS, so you better validate this params out of the template and pass only valid values to the template - but in general, the way I mentioned is the way to reach the `$_COOKIE` global